# Combine my two MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

This is erp.orders:

```
userId  paidAt
1       2017-06-30
1       2017-06-18
2       2017-06-07
4       2017-06-07
3       2017-01-01
2       2017-01-01
2       2017-01-01
2       2017-01-01
```

This is prod.referral_order_delivered

```
user_id
1
2
1
1
1
```

I need to combine two requests.

This request :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    erp.orders.userid, COUNT(erp.orders.userid) as countorders
FROM 
    erp.orders
WHERE 
    erp.orders.userid IN (SELECT erp.orders.userid
                          FROM erp.orders, prod.referral_order_delivered
                          WHERE erp.orders.userid = prod.referral_order_delivered.user_id
                            AND erp.orders.paidat::date >= '2017-06-07'
                            AND erp.orders.paidat::date <= '2017-07-07')
GROUP BY 
    erp.orders.userid;
```

This returns this result:

```
userId  countorders
1           2
2           4
```

And this request:

```
SELECT 
    prod.referral_order_delivered.user_id,
    COUNT(prod.referral_order_delivered.user_id) AS countreferral
FROM 
    prod.referral_order_delivered
WHERE 
    prod.referral_order_delivered.user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT erp.orders.userid
                                              FROM erp.orders
                                              INNER JOIN prod.referral_order_delivered ON erp.orders.userid = prod.referral_order_delivered.user_id
                                              WHERE erp.orders.paidat >= '2017-06-07'
                                                AND erp.orders.paidat <= '2017-07-07')
GROUP BY 
    prod.referral_order_delivered.user_id
```

which returns this result:

```
user_id    countreferral
1          4
2          1
```

Now I want to combine these requests to get this result:

```
userId  countorders countreferral
1       2           4
2       4           1
```

Note that user_id and userId is the same thing. So it doesn't matter if this is user_id or userId which appears.

You can test the solution [here](http://rextester.com/ZAFH74566).

Comment: Not bad, but please see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I don't really see how I could have asked my question better, even when I read the post you gave me. Please tell me yourself, so that I improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider joining the two aggregate queries as derived tables. First, convert the `IN` clause queries (both of which are equivalent with former using *implicit join* and latter with *explicit join*) to `JOIN` clauses. Then, run same aggregations with outer query joining both and selecting columns.

```
SELECT agg1.userid, agg1.countorders, agg2.countreferral
FROM
   (SELECT j.userid, COUNT(j.userid) as countorders
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT erp.orders.userid
         FROM erp.orders
         INNER JOIN prod.referral_order_delivered 
             ON erp.orders.userid = prod.referral_order_delivered.user_id
         WHERE erp.orders.paidat >= '2017-06-07'
           AND erp.orders.paidat <= '2017-07-07') j

    INNER JOIN erp.orders e ON j.userid = e.userid
    GROUP BY j.userid) agg1

INNER JOIN   
   (SELECT j.userid, COUNT(j.userid) as countreferral
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT erp.orders.userid
         FROM erp.orders
         INNER JOIN prod.referral_order_delivered 
             ON erp.orders.userid = prod.referral_order_delivered.user_id
         WHERE erp.orders.paidat >= '2017-06-07'
           AND erp.orders.paidat <= '2017-07-07') j

    INNER JOIN prod.referral_order_delivered p ON j.userid = p.user_id
    GROUP BY j.userid) agg2

ON agg1.userid = agg2.userid
```

Even save the nested inner query used in the source of both aggregates as a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html).

```
SELECT agg1.userid, agg1.countorders, agg2.countreferral
FROM
   (SELECT v.userid, COUNT(j.userid) as countorders
    FROM myview v           
    INNER JOIN erp.orders e ON v.userid = e.userid
    GROUP BY v.userid) agg1

INNER JOIN   
   (SELECT v.userid, COUNT(j.userid) as countreferral
    FROM myview v         
    INNER JOIN prod.referral_order_delivered p ON v.userid = p.user_id
    GROUP BY v.userid) agg2

ON agg1.userid = agg2.userid
```

In other RDBMS's like Postgres unlike MySQL you could use CTE's `WITH()` to avoid repetition. See [rextester demo](http://rextester.com/NQTJD83563) forked from your initial setup.

Comment: How do you format your querries in this very nice way? You do it manually?

Comment: Great! Glad to help. I simply format manually with line breaks and spaces, trying to organize clauses for readability: `SELECT`, `FROM`, `JOIN`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`. And indent any subqueries.